# Disable Editing in Outlook 2013 Reading Pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

With Outlook 2013, the reading pane allows to edit e.g. drafts and tasks without opening them.

How can I disable this editing in order to make the reading pane strictly read-only (as it was with previous version of Outlook?)

Comment: Do you mean if you click reply, you always want it to pop out?

Comment: @Dave No, my question is to disable all editing in the reading pane. But disabling the inline replies does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Outlook 2013 introduces the in-line reply feature, which allows you to
>   reply to an email directly in the Reading pane, instead of opening a
>   separate window. However, if you prefer to use the separate message
>   editing window, there is an easy way to access it.
>
> NOTE: If you have the Reading pane active but you can’t see the
>   selected email in it, the People pane might be in the way. To hide the
>   People pane, click the down arrow on the far right of the top of the
>   pane.

[image]

> You should see the Reply, Reply All and Forward buttons at the top of
>   the message in the Reading pane. Click one of these buttons to reply
>   to or forward the currently selected message.

[image]

> A simple editing pane displays directly in the Reading pane. To access
>   a separate message editing window for writing your reply or forwarding
>   an email, click Pop Out above the Send button on the message.
>
> NOTE: If you decide not to reply to or forward this email, click
>   Discard.

[image]

> You can choose to always display the separate message editing window
>   when replying to or forwarding emails. To do this, click the File tab
>   on the main Outlook window.

[image]

> Click Options on the left side of the Account Information screen.

[image]

On the Outlook Options dialog box, click Mail in the list of options on the left.

[image]

> On the Mail screen, scroll down to the Replies and forwards section
>   and select the Open replies and forwards in a new window check box.
>   Click OK to save the change and close the dialog box.

[image]

> Now, whenever you reply to an email or forward an email, a separate
>   message editing window will display.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/172625/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-separate-message-editing-window-for-replies-in-outlook-2013/)

Comment: Well, that’s a bit lengthy for “Open replies and forward messages in a new window” in the mail settings will disable editing. But it works :)

Comment: @Martin - All I did was quote the article.

Answer (score 3):

To always reply in the pop-up box You can enable it here.

[image: Outlook Open Replies In New Window]

[Sauce](http://www.howtogeek.com/172625/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-separate-message-editing-window-for-replies-in-outlook-2013/)